# Why does this variable eloquent method work and how can I pass args?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Quick question, why does this do what I want it to?

```
<?php $method = 'name'; ?>

@if($model->$method == 'Joe')
...
```

When I run that, it substitutes $method for 'name', just like I would want it to. Which is awesome for what I am trying to do! Problem is, if this were my project, then I am also trying to pass 2 arguments back to the Model through 'name', but when I do this, it stops working:

```
<?php $method = 'name'; ?>

@if($model->$method($argument) == 'Joe')
...
```

So I've been googling and haven't found any reason why this works in the first place, and I sure would like it to work in the second one. Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** Never mind! I got it to work with passing args. I'd still like to know if somebody can find this in the Laravel docs or something? I have no idea what to even call this.

Comment: It works and Laravel doesn't mention it because it's a PHP feature: https://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!